# Debian 12 Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, debian, docker

I have a docker file based on the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` image. As part of the file I am installing the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package with the following commands:

```
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free'
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig
```

This worked fine until I updated the base image to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0` where I started getting the following error:

```
Package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate
ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

I tried update the repository I'm adding to bookworm with the same result. I can't find any information that the package has changed location or is no longer available. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: `updated the base image to mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` updated from what? I mean, what was the base image before you updated to that one, since that's the only one you mention

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, typo. I updated it from 7.0 -> 8.0. Have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command does not work:

```
add-apt-repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free'
```

I don't know why, IMO it should, but it does not add the desired sections. Not even with the correct codename (Debian 12 is bookworm, not bullseye). Maybe a bug, it only adds an empty file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

You can use the following command instead:

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/contrib.list
```

Afterwards the installation works.

Bonus: You don't even need the `software-properties-common` and all it's dependencies only to add a single line file, reducing your image size by 130 MB.